# What are the errors in my code with NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

There is such a task:
Need to implement a program. The program has a text box and the ability to open text files and paste text from a file into this text box.
Also, the program should record audio. For this, I use the NAudio library.
When you press CTRL + 1, audio is recording. When you press CTRL + 2, stop record.
Each file is recorded by record number. The number is incremented after each entry.
I implemented the program correctly, I took the code from NAudio from the article about recording audio in C # through NAudio. There was a write code right there in the button event, but I implemented separate methods.
As a result, Visual Studio produces a list of errors.
Please help me figure it out.
Form File Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.FileFormats;
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;
using NAudio;
 
namespace RecordBooks
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WaveIn waveIn;
        WaveFileWriter writer;
        string recordFile = "";
        int numberRecords = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyPreview = true;
            KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
        }
 
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
            {
                StartRecording();
            }
            else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.D2)
            {
                if (waveIn != null)
                {
                    StopRecording();
                }
            }
        }
 
        void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveIn_DataAvailable), sender, e);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            }
        }
 
        void StartRecording()
        {
            try
            {
                waveIn = new WaveIn();
                waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
                waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
                waveIn.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler(waveIn_RecordingStopped);
                waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 1);
                recordFile = numberRecords + ".wav";
                writer = new WaveFileWriter(recordFile);
                waveIn.StartRecording();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
 
            void StopRecording()
            {
                waveIn.StopRecording();
                numberRecords += 1;
            }
 
            void waveIn_RecordingStopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(waveIn_RecordingStopped), sender, e);
                }
                else
                {
                    waveIn.Dispose();
                    waveIn = null;
                    writer.Close();
                    writer = null;
                }
            }
 
            void menuNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                richTextBox1.Clear();
                numberRecords = 0;
            }
 
            void menuExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
 
            void menuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && openFileDialog1.FileName.Length > 0)
                {
                    richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                    numberRecords = 0;
                }
            }
 
            void menuSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the errors you get?

Comment: https://i.paste.pics/2f7a200fbd070b1f2b0a616b29197dca.png

Answer (score 0):

You did not close the method StartRecording() with a `}`. Therefore all following methods are local to StartRecording and not visible outside.

```
void StartRecording()
{
    try
    {
        waveIn = new WaveIn();
        waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
        waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
        waveIn.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler(waveIn_RecordingStopped);
        waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 1);
        recordFile = numberRecords + ".wav";
        writer = new WaveFileWriter(recordFile);
        waveIn.StartRecording();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
 } // <<<-- this was missing

 void StopRecording()
 {
    waveIn.StopRecording();
    numberRecords += 1;
 }
```

Comment: Errors remained

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear. Do you get the same error messages? If they are different now, please post the new ones (better edit your question for this than adding another comment, also better add the error messages as text, not as picture).

Comment: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.StoppedEventArgs>' RecordBooks

Comment: The error message also includes a line number; and double-clicking on the error message will get you to the offending line in the visual studio code editor. Probably it is this one: `waveIn.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler(waveIn_RecordingStopped);`; change it to `waveIn.RecordingStopped += waveIn_RecordingStopped;` and alco correct the method signature of waveIn_RecordingStopped to `void waveIn_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)`

Comment: CS0123 No overload for 'waveIn_RecordingStopped' matches delegate 'EventHandler' RecordBooks Line 86

Comment: This is probably the line `this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(waveIn_RecordingStopped), sender, e);`. Also here, remove the superfluous and wrong `new EventHandler(` leaving just `this.BeginInvoke(waveIn_RecordingStopped, sender, e);`

Comment: Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Delegate' RecordBooks Line 86